# About PHP statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Can anyone help me to make code for this statement

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $single = true) != ""){ ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "price",$single = true); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

If in my custom field empty i want the  statement continue with this code

```
<?php $asin = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'asin', true);
echo azon_us_price($asin);
 ?>
```

Comment: hi Null, in post meta with price id, if in the price id is empty i want statement continue with second statement and display result from there

Comment: what is price id $post->ID ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
<?php
if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $single = true))){ 
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "price",$single = true); 
} else {
  $asin = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'asin', true);
  echo azon_us_price($asin);
}
?>
```